# Public key Required to verify the JWT issued by AzDO

Tags: azure-devops

I have a JWT issued by app.vstoken.visualstudio.com.
When I tried to do validate that token using

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.Validate();
```

its throwing following exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
```

I suspect its because its not able to locate the public key for the issuer having

> thumbprint = x5t attribute value present in the JWT header

How to get that public certificate or how to tell JwtSecurityTokenHandler.Validate() to fetch the required certificate to validate the JWT signature.

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)? What do you want to achieve in Azure DevOps?

Comment: The context is<
I have a service lets call it serviceX, it supports windows authentication for authorizing clients.
One of my client is operating through docker and he could not access Key Distribution Server, so we need to add some other form of authentication to ServiceX.
We are thinking of using jwt token issued by dev.azure.com/some-org because that is the only info available in the client's docker.
Our client will forward us that JWT token and we will validate it with  AzDO to allow access. We both want to trust AzDO with the token it is generating.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to develop an extension in DevOps? Is this what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/auth?view=azure-devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach was to validate token issued by remote website locally.
To validate locally I needed to validate signature of the token using public key of the remote website (since it has used its private key to sign the token).
But instead of doing that I found out that the remote website exposes set of rest apis accessing which requires user to provide valid token as part of "bearer" header in the http request.
Currently I am using that api to determine authenticity of the user.

The remote website was dev.azure.com and it exposes set of apis and sdk to authenticate the token.
Library used :  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi